# How to get the SeekBar work to adjust brightness

Tags: android, seekbar, brightness

First of all, I am new to Android Developing so don't be so harsh on me.

I have tried to get the SeekBar to adjust the brightness level of either the application or the entire system. Although, I have not been able to get this to work.

My XML-file looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SettingsPage" >

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML code for MainActivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSettings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:onClick="settingsPage"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML code, the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testsetup"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-sdk

    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testsetup.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testsetup.SettingsPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings_page" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testsetup.BrightnessAdjuster"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brightness_adjuster" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.testsetup.BrightnessActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_brightness" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Java-code that I have looks like this:

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.WindowManager;
   import android.widget.SeekBar;
   import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
   import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SettingsPage extends Activity {

float BackLightValue = 0.5f; // dummy default value


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_page);
    SeekBar BackLightControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

    BackLightControl
            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener());
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    int SysBackLightValue = (int) (BackLightValue * 255);
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
            SysBackLightValue);

}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
    BackLightValue = (float) arg1 / 100;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings_page, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Java code for MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void settingsPage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

The problem is that I do not know if this is the right way, even though I have tried to follow several guides on the matter.

Also, I get one error in the above code, and it is the following line

```
BackLightControl
        .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener());
```

I get the error that "cannot instantiate type SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()".
I thought it was due to the fact that OnSeekBarChangeListener was an interface, so I tried to create a random class that implemented OnSeekBarChangeListener and instantiate that class, but that did not work either.

So, now is my question; how to proceed from here?

Regards and thanks in advance

Erik

*EDIT*

Added my other classes and XML files. Plus, I no longer get the error on the line with instantiating the OnSeekBarChangeListener thing.

Regards

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot in instantiate `OnSeekBarChangeListener` because it's an **`interface`**. If you create a class which implements this interface, and use an instance of that class as the parameter of `setOnSeekBarChangeListener`, that should definitely work. The easiest way is letting your `Activity` implement `OnSeekBarChangeListener`, and pass `this` to the setter method.

```
public class SettingsPage extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_page);
        SeekBar BackLightControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);

        BackLightControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

*Side note: you should use standard Java naming conventions, variable names start with lowercase characters.*

Comment: Now, I did as you proposed, but now, the application crashes when I hit the "Button" button in the MainActivity. The only thing I've changed is the naming (small letters in variable names) and the thing you proposed. I will add the MainAcitivity code in my first question, including the XML files and the XML manifest.

Comment: You use this line: `SeekBar BackLightControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);`
I see no `SeekBar` declared with this id, therefore the method returns null, and you got a `NullPointerException`. You should use the id wich is actually in your layout. For example `R.id.seekBar`. Also you have to import your `R` class, not the built-in `android.R`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it and it now works, although I did not import my R class as instructed. However, when I drag the seekbar cursor to the leftmost position, the screen goes entirely black and I do not see anything. Do you know a good fix for this as well? :)

But, if you do not, many thanks.

Comment: You can use a lower bound to the `SysBackLightValue` variable, for example: `if (SysBackLightValue < 20) {SysBackLightValue = 20;}` In this way you prevent to lightness to go entirely black. Note that the value 20 may be not correct, play with it.